# YOLOv5 как вывести результат от Torch на OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch

В чём суть
Делаю распознание врагов и тимейтов для кс:го
Нейросеть я обучил, но могу смотреть результат только через detect.py.
Но мне надо что-бы он мог в реальном времени распознавать
Делал через Torch, мог только видеть скриншот который даёт resultat.show()
Брал из официальной [Документации](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5)
Но не как не мог этот resultat.show() использовать как cv2.imshow('example', resultat)
Но мне нужно! Но не знаю как

Помогите пожалуйста,
Думаю понятно объяснил ;)

Comment: нет, непонятно объяснил.

Comment: А что именно не понятно?

Comment: Приведи пример кода, который есть. Так это гадание на кофейной гуще. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture() # Тут ссылка на стрим с твоего экрана
while(cap.isOpened()):
 frame = cap.read() # твой кадр в np.array (float.64)
 ...
 прогон через inference, функцией draw - рисуешь bbox'ы
 ...
 cv.imshow(new_frame)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).